# ECIES: Purpose of optional shared information?

Tags: elliptic-curves, mac, key-derivation, ecies

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Integrated_Encryption_Scheme&oldid=598845238) the *ECIES* algorithm has two optional shared information $S_1$ and $S_2$. They are used as follows:

1. Generate a random shared secret $Z$ according to *ECIES*, which will never be reused
2. Derive symmetric keys $k_1|k_2=KDF(Z_x|S_1)$
3. Encrypt the message $c=\text{ENCRYPT}_{k_1}(m)$
4. Tag the encrypted message $t=\text{MAC}_{k_2}(c|S_2)$

**Question 1:**
Assume:

- $S_1$ and $S_2$ are randomly generated for each message and send with it in plain text.

Whats the purpose of $S_1$ and $S_2$ in this case? Whats the use of $S_2$ if $S_1$ is set properly?

**Question 2:** Assume:

- $Z$ is not randomly generated for each message (e.g. using a static key pair)
- $S_1$ and $S_2$ are empty

Is this mode secure? Or should it be avoided?

**Question 3:** Assume:

- $Z$ is not randomly generated for each message (e.g. using a static key pair)
- $S_1$ is a unique endless counter and send with the message in plain text

What is the purpose of $S_2$? Is it less secure to not use $S_2$?